# Beautify and restore variable names to a js file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, minify

After using grunt.js to minify my code, how would I beautify the code again and restore the variable names (as if I had never minified it in the first place)?

I have found a lot on here about jsbeautifier.org but that doesn't help me if I need all the variable names restored

Comment: Save a copy of your unminified code.

Comment: You can't, that's the whole purpose of minifying, it is a 1 way change to make your code smaller. If you however generate a sourcemap with the code you should be able to read the minified code in a compliant browser and possibly reverse generate the code.

Comment: how can you get something from nothing?

Comment: I'm trying to send js stack-traces to an analytics server... unfortunately the js is minified/uglified in the clients browser, so by the time I get it it's very hard to analyze.  I could see this being very useful if it could somehow un minify a stack-trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you probably want to save a copy of the original (un-minified/ un-uglified) code, but if you do need to revert back from minified code you could use source maps.  Check 'em out [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/).

Answer (score -1):

The purpose of minifier is to obfuscate the code. You don't want to be able to unminify a minified file.
You want to keep the original file and you can also generate a sourcemap that'll link the minified file with the original.

Comment: The purpose of minifying your code is actually to create smaller file sizes to serve from your server.  If you want to obfuscate your code, you also have to use a code obfuscator, like this one: https://jscrambler.com/